# How to set up an image to be used with openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a big image that I want to display on my website, and allow people to navigate it like a map (zoom and move around).

OpenLayers 3 seems to be a good technology for the client side.

Now the question is: how do I set up the server side so that it can serve the image tiles in a way that works with OpenLayers?

Note that there is no "geographical data" to be displayed, just a plain image.

More details: the server side is a pretty common apache+php host. Ideally, I'd just want to split the image with an automatic tool and upload it, and let openlayers take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly use a service like http://www.maptiler.com/ ?

It looks like you can add non-georeferenced raster images, and have it create tiles for you.  Then the tiles could be hosted on your server and used with OL3 or whatever client-side mapping tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is not *prohibitevely* big you could use the `ol.layer.Image` layer that allows feeding a static image from a URL to it. This has the benefit that you can use the image as-is, without having to split it into tiles or use some fancy protocol to communicate with the tiles server.

There is an [official live example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/static-image.html) with code included.